# Shouldn't BackgroundSubtractor.apply() return a binary mask?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV (wrapped in Java, but that's not important I believe).

I'm trying to detect the foreground using 10 pictures through `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`. Here's code, if helps:

```
    Mat frame = new Mat();
    Mat result = new Mat();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        frame = imRead(...+i+...);
        subtractor.apply(frame, result, 0.05);
    }

    frame = imRead(...); //frame whose foreground I'm interested 
    subtractor.apply(frame, result, 0.05);
```

I expect `result` to be, as stated [in the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/video/BackgroundSubtractor.html#apply(org.opencv.core.Mat, org.opencv.core.Mat, double)), a *mask*; a *binary image*. However, as I discovered both visually and through code, it is not B/W and has lots of grays.

*Unique values in the resulting matrix*

```
 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  120  121  122  123  124  125   126  127  128  129  130  131  132  133  134  135  245  247   248  249  250  251   252  253  254  255
```

*Casually zoomed-in picture: see the gray*

[image]

- How should I interpret values different than 0 or 255? What do they mean?
- What is the best way to get a *real* mask from this? I could set a threshold and flatten to 0 down, 255 up, but which threshold is the most reasonable? 1, 128, 254?

I might add that, of course, 0s and 255s are the predominant values, but still I'm not ok with a greyscale image - I need it black and white.

---

@Miki

*Going through OpenCV code, you should only get 0, 255, and (if shadow detection is enabled) 127.* - thank you, I disabled shadow detection and I'm getting way better results. However, to disable it I need to call [this constructor](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/video/BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.html#BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(int, float, boolean)): `new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(int history, float varThreshold, boolean shadowEnabled)`. Documentation is very poor (to me at least), and I don't know what to put in the first two fields. Could you help me or point me to the default values? Moreover, are these two parameters somehow linked to the `0.05` I'm using in my code? (I don't know what it is, it just happened to work good in respect to other values I have tried).

*Do you perform some other operations in your code that can affect this value?* - well, writing the image to a file and reading it with MATLAB. Could it be the jpg compression format? If so I'm quite surprised, the loss is huge (look at those unique values!).

Comment: Going through OpenCV code, you should only get 0, 255, and (if shadow detection is enabled) 127. I run some tests and I got only these 3 values. Do you perform some other operations in your code that can affect this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output mask will have values:

```
0   : background 
255 : foreground 
127 : shadow (only if shadow detection is enabled, default = true)
```

You can enable and disable shadow detection in the constructor:

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(int history, float varThreshold, boolean bShadowDetection)
```

where:

- **history** : Length of the history.
- **varThreshold** : Threshold on the squared Mahalanobis distance to decide whether it is well described by the background model (see Cthr??). This parameter does not affect the background update. A typical value could be 4 sigma, that is, varThreshold=4*4=16;
- **bShadowDetection** – Parameter defining whether shadow detection should be enabled (true or false).

The default values (set in the constructor with no arguments) are:

```
histoty = 500;
varThreshold = 4.0f*4.0f;
```

The values in the background mask are set in this line:

```
// bgfg_gaussmix2.cpp

mask[x] = background ? 0 :
                detectShadows && detectShadowGMM(data, nchannels, nmodes, gmm, mean, Tb, TB, tau) ?
                shadowVal : 255;
```

where the value of `shadowVal` is set equal to `defaultnShadowDetection2`

```
static const unsigned char defaultnShadowDetection2 = (unsigned char)127;
```

So, the values in the mask are only `0`, `255`, and `127` (if shadow detection is enabled).

If you saved your image in *jpeg* format, the compression would create those other values as compression artifacts. Save the image in a lossless format like *png*.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question adding replies to your answer - too big for a comment.

Comment: @mvai updated the answer. Your issue is caused by saving the image in _jpeg_ (compressed format). Save the image in a lossless format like _png_ and you'll be ok.

Comment: @mvai the value 0.5 is the _learningRate_ rate. Is not related to the other values in the constructor, but impacts on the update of the GMM model. _speed of update - if the time interval you want to average over is Tset alpha=1/T. It is also usefull at start to make T slowly increase from 1 until the desired T_

Comment: I went deeper into the papers and I believe you are not right in the first sentence - the `learningRate` *is* related to the first param in the constructor, `history`, because `history` is the T you are mentioning below (`learningRate = 1/history`). By calling `apply(learningRate)`, I believe one overrides the learningRate previously set in the constructor through `history`.

Comment: @mvai It makes sense. I should go into the code to check if something is actually overwritten or not, but I can't right now.

Comment: Makes sense, but from my tests I have discovered that `history` is just useless, has no effect on the result, and it all boils down to what you put in `apply()`. This is strange and I have just asked [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32440419/4288782) about it.