# What is the meaning of "history" inside BackgroundSubtractorMOG2?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-segmentation

I'm on OpenCV for java (but that's not relevant I guess). I'm using the `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` class which is (poorly) referenced [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/video/BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.html). I have read and understood the Zivkovic paper about the algorithm which you can find [here](http://www.zoranz.net/Publications/zivkovic2004ICPR.pdf).

`BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` takes in its constructor a parameter called `history`. What is it, and how does it influence the result? Could you point me to its reference inside the paper, for example?

From the [class source code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/video/src/bgfg_gaussmix2.cpp), line 106, it is said that `alpha = 1/history`. That would mean that history is namely the T parameter inside the paper, i.e. (more or less) the number of frames that constitute the training set.

However it doesn't seem so. Changing the value in the constructor, from 10 to 500 or beyond, has *no effect* on the final result. This is what I'm calling:

```
Mat result = new Mat();
int history = 10; //or 50, or 500, or whatever
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 sub = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history, 16, false);
for (....) {
    sub.apply(frame[i], result);
}
imshow(result); //let's see last frame
```

It doesn't matter what history I set, be it 5, 10, 500, 1000 - the result is always the same. Whereas, if I change the `alpha` value (the learning rate) through `apply()`, I can see its real influence:

```
Mat result = new Mat();
float alpha = 0.1; //learning rate, 1/T (1/history?)
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 sub = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(whatever, 16, false);
for (...) {
    sub.apply(frame[i], result, alpha);
}
imshow(result);
```

If I change alpha here, result changes a lot, which is understandable. So, two conjectures:

1. `history` is not really `1/alpha` as the source code states. But then: what is it? how does it affect the algorithm?
2. `history` is really `1/alpha`, but there's a bug in the java wrapper that makes the `history` value you set in the constructor useless.

Could you help me?

*(Tagging c++ also as this is mainly a question about an OpenCV class and the whole OpenCV java framework is just a wrapper around c++)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems clear that `alpha = 1 / history` (except for some transitory instants). In void `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2Impl::apply` method:

```
learningRate = learningRate >= 0 && nframes > 1 ? learningRate : 1./std::min( 2*nframes, history );
```

You can test if the `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` object is using the history value that you pass in the constructor using the `getHistory()` method.

Comment: That is what I had understood, but my tests are against, as I have shown - changing history doesn't change the result. Seeing your line, maybe that is because `2*nframes < history`? Will check it out. I could do some debugging with `getHistory()`, but there's no such method in java.

Comment: That `min` means that in the very first frame it is using `alpha = 0.5`, then slowly going down to `alpha = 1/history`. Interesting.