# How can I make openCV Backgroundsubtraction KNN algorithm last longer, tracking a foregound object which is not moving

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, background-subtraction

I am trying to substract this building brick. [image: orange building brick]
.

For that I am using the KNN algorithm provided by opencv 3.0.
To initialize the background model I am using 40 frames without the brick.

All in all it works pretty well.
(Brick with Shadow)
[image]

The only problem is that the algorithm starts loosing the brick around Frame 58

(Image shows frame 62)

[image]

After frame 64 I get only black images. I know this wouldn't happen if the brick would move, but unfortunatly there are long sequences where it doesn`t.

Does somebody know a solution to this?

PS: I tried playing around with the history Paramer of

```
cv::createBackgroundSubtractorKNN(int history,double Threshold, bool detectShadows= true)
```

But there is no difference between `history = 500 or history = 500000`

Comment: possibly related:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440419/what-is-the-meaning-of-history-inside-backgroundsubtractormog2

Comment: Yeah it's a related question, but sadly nobody answered his question.
Maybe I am more lucky with my question. Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A easy but slow solution is to reinitialize the background model every five frames.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++){
    if (i % 5 == 0){
        for (auto& it : backgroundList){

            string nextFrameFilename(it.string());
            frame = cv::imread(nextFrameFilename);
            pMOG->apply(frame, fgMaskMOG2);
            imshow("Frame", frame);
            imshow("FG Mask MOG 2", fgMaskMOG2);
            keyboard = cv::waitKey(30);
        }
    }
}
```